# JavaScript - Opacity animation then hide page elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the JavaScript that I have for the main navigation on my website. When the user clicks a link the content under all Id's besides the link they choose is hidden by setting the opacity to 0. However I soon realised that links are still clickable. What edit can I make to this JavaScript to keep the opacity animation but after the animation is complete hide the content completely so links included are not visible?

JavaScript Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    /* How to Handle Hashtags */
    jQuery(window).hashchange(function(){
        var hash = location.hash;
        jQuery('a[href='+hash+']').trigger('click');
    });

    /* Main Navigation Clicks */
    jQuery('.main-nav ul li a').click(function() {
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(1);

        if ( !jQuery('section.content.show, section#' + link).is(':animated') ) {
            jQuery('.main-nav ul li a').removeClass('active'); //remove active
            jQuery('section.content.show').addClass('show').animate({'opacity' : 0}, {queue: false, duration: 1000,
                complete: function() {
                    jQuery('a[href="#'+link+'"]').addClass('active'); // add active
                    jQuery('section#' + link).addClass('show').animate({'opacity' : 1}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Gah, should I change realised to realized?  I'm from the US!

Comment: Set the visibility to hidden at the end of the animation. Note you also need to set visibility to visible at the start of animating back the opacity

Comment: Could you show an example? JS isn't my best language.

Comment: I think just having it hide on the animation call back will do what you want ie: `...addClass(...).animate(...).hide()`

Comment: Why not just call [fadeOut(1000)](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)?

Comment: Would I put that after ({'opacity' : 0},?

Comment: I don't think just setting the opacity is going to prevent you from clicking on an element. Take a look at this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hPNxU/). I don't know exactly how your page is laid out or anything so I just threw in a few links and sections similar to your jQuery. I also added a click event on the links in the `section` areas, just to make sure the clicks were not being picked up after they were hidden. Is this along the lines of what you are trying to do?

Comment: `jQuery('.main-nav ul li a').click(…)` - Please slap the person who wrote this. (For the uninformed, it should be `$('.main-nav').on('click', 'a', …)`.)

Comment: You must think I'm a pain but JS is an area I haven't yet touched. Could you possibly change what is needed from the code above and post it back? Thanks